# Azure MySQL root privilege

Tags: mysql, azure, privileges

I create a MySQL database on Azure with a "Mercury" princing level, I log myself in MySQL Workbench, but I can't add an user or change privileges with "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ... "  I get "Access denied for user x". (I logged with the username and password that Azure give me). 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Some Cloud Mysql restrict user's privileges just like alisql. You even can not access the mysql.user table.

You can just use the account which is created in web page and create users in web page. The account you used has not super privilege. So you can not execute "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ... " to create super privilege account.

If you want to get super privileges, you can try as follows:

1. Buy the azure host and install mysql yourself
2. Ask azure supportwhether you can have root account
3. Change another cloud mysql which has root privileges like 'UCloud'

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with root privileges, this functionality is not available for this specific database provider. The default `MySQL` database provider in `Azure` for now is `ClearDB`, and I'm afraid you are not able to [create more users for the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/store-cleardb-faq):

> Can I create additional users for my `ClearDB` `MySQL` database cluster solution?
>
> No. You cannot create additional users but you can create additional databases on your `ClearDB` database cluster